# Create a file about "DriveApp.createFile"

Tags: google-api, drive, createfile

i try to create a Google-Sheet-File about the command "DriveApp.createFile....". When i run my script i get always the error back "wrong argument".

```
function myFunction() {
  // This command is Running
  DriveApp.createFile('New HTML File', '<b>Hello, world!</b>', MimeType.HTML);

  // This command is NOT Running
  DriveApp.createFile('DOC', 'Hello, world!', MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  DriveApp.cre
}
```

[Link to the Google-Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String))

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where is my fault?

Thanks

Comment: Are there some reasons that [``SpreadsheetApp.create(name)``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) cannot be used?

Comment: Yes, in my case I was doing a function that takes the mime type as parameter and should create a file of that type in a drive folder.

Answer (score 1):

DriveApp.createFile() does not support GOOGLE_SHEETS anymore. You can alternatively use DRIVE API to do the same.

```
var resource = {
      title: name,
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      parents: [{ id: folderId }]
    };  
var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
```